# Ubuntu: Can't connect to host's internet connection using NAT

Tags: ubuntu, networking, connection, virtualbox

I installed Lubuntu on Virtualbox.  I'm using Windows 7 x64.  My VM is 32 bit version.  The internet works using Bridged Adapter, but I'm trying to use NAT so I can use a VPN.  In Network and Sharing Center in Windows, I see connection "VirtualBox Host-Only Connection" and it says "No Internet Access".  In properties, "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver" is checked.  The following is the output of ifconfig:

```
dev@dev-VirtualBox:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f3:48:24  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef3:4824/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32105 (32.1 KB)  TX bytes:34987 (34.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:56432 (56.4 KB)  TX bytes:56432 (56.4 KB)
```

Routing Table:

```
dev@dev-VirtualBox:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
dev@dev-VirtualBox:~$
```

Connection Editor:
General: Automatically Connect to this network when it isn't available, All users may connect ot this network
Ethernet: MTU automatic
IPV4: Automatic (DHCP), Require ipv4 addressing for this connection to complete
IPV6: Ignore

```
dev@dev-VirtualBox:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that NetworkManager was not updating /etc/resolv.conf with the nameservers.

Commenting out dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf worked after rebooting.

From here (the first solution didn't work for me)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/137037/networkmanager-not-populating-resolv-conf

Answer (score 0):

Just type this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this, you can try the following.

**Check VirtualBox Configuration**

Open VirtualBox Manager -> Open Machine Setting -> Select "Network":

- Enable Netowrk Adapter: check
- Attached to: NAT
- Cable Connected: check

**Check the status of your interfaces**

```
ip address show
```

> 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
> link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
> inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
> inet6 ::1/128 scope host
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

> 2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,**UP**,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
> link/ether 08:00:27:c7:e3:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
> **inet 10.0.2.15/24** brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
> valid_lft 81707sec preferred_lft 81707sec
> inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fec7:e3b9/64 scope link
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

> 3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
> link/ether 02:42:b1:8f:dd:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
> inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
> valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

In this step you may want to check two things: if the interface is up and if you have an IP address assigned.

**Enable the Network Interface**

```
sudo ip link set enp0s3 up
```

**Request new IP address from DHCP**

```
sudo dhclient -r enp0s3
sudo dhclient enp0s3
```